# Best way of storing matrix of DNA in python

Tags: python

I would like to store character arrays of DNA in Python, each word as each element.

For example, I would like to change

```
 1. cctgatagacgctatctggctatccaggtacttaggtcctctgtgcgaatctatgcgtttccaaccat
 2. agtactggtgtacatttgatccatacgtacaccggcaacctgaaacaaacgctcagaaccagaagtgc
 3. aaacgttagtgcaccctctttcttcgtggctctggccaacgagggctgatgtataagacgaaaatttt
 4. agcctccgatgtaagtcatagctgtaactattacctgccacccctattacatcttacgtccatataca
 5. ctgttatacaacgcgtcatggcggggtatgcgttttggtcgtcgtacgctcgatcgttaccgtacggc
```

into a 2D matrix form, with each element storing a single character. I've thought of **numpy**, but I think it might not be suitable for these character strings.

What is the best way in Python?

Comment: Maybe a [`bytearray`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bytearray) with each byte encoding 4 amino acids, assuming what you are trying to achieve is maximum memory efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

The simple obvious answer is to use a list of lists:

```
a = "cctgatagacgctatctggctatccaggtacttaggtcctctgtgcgaatctatgcgtttccaaccat"
b = "agtactggtgtacatttgatccatacgtacaccggcaacctgaaacaaacgctcagaaccagaagtgc"
matrix = [list(a), list(b)]
print(matrix)

[
  ['c', 'c', 't', 'g', 'a', 't', 'a', 'g', 'a', 'c', 'g', 'c', 't', 'a', 't', 'c', 't', 'g', 'g', 'c', 't', 'a', 't', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'g', 'g', 't', 'a', 'c', 't', 't', 'a', 'g', 'g', 't', 'c', 'c', 't', 'c', 't', 'g', 't', 'g', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'a', 't', 'c', 't', 'a', 't', 'g', 'c', 'g', 't', 't', 't', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 't'], 
  ['a', 'g', 't', 'a', 'c', 't', 'g', 'g', 't', 'g', 't', 'a', 'c', 'a', 't', 't', 't', 'g', 'a', 't', 'c', 'c', 'a', 't', 'a', 'c', 'g', 't', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'g', 'g', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 't', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'g', 'c', 't', 'c', 'a', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 't', 'g', 'c']
]
```

Now whether it's the right solution for you depends on how you plan to use this, how large your datasets are going to be, performances and memory use contraints etc, none of which are mentionned in your question...

Comment: @DrorPaz strings are immutable so any editing would be inefficient.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog  - You're right. comment deleted and bruno desthuilliers upvoted.

Comment: @DrorPaz that said they are still more efficient for pure storage, so it depends on the OP's requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as a list of [`Seq`](https://biopython.org/wiki/Seq) objects from the [Biopython](https://biopython.org/) library designed specifically to handle biological sequences like DNA or amino acid chains.
The library has some great methods designed specifically for DNA sequences, like `reverse_complement()` or `transcribe()`. Heaven for a bioinformatician!

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
my_seq1 = Seq("AGTACACTGGT")
my_seq2 = Seq("GATTAGCTGAT")

list = [my_seq1, my_seq2]
```